# Fetching specific JSON data with iOS / Make a query

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, wordpress

I have installed the **JSON api** from wordpress on my website. I've to retrieve pictures from a website with wordpress and some specific content which are in the content page, and use it in **iOS app** with JSON.

Here is the JSON data that I receive :

```
<p><strong style=\"font-size: 13px;\">3rd March</strong></p>\n<p>Swell is 5 foot and cross shore, bitter in the cold wind. Maybe streedagh.</p>\n<p><span id=\"more-113\"></span></p>\n<p>High tide: 1703 3.6m    <span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"> <a href=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/webcam/\"><strong>CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM</strong></a></span></p>\n<p>Low Tide: 1041 0.8m</p>\n<p><b>3 day forecast to March 5th</b></p>\n<p>Good swell all weekend but the winds are changing. Keep in an eye for gaps in the wind.</p>\n\n\t\t<style type='text/css'>\n\t\t\t#gallery-1 {\n\t\t\t\tmargin: auto;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t#gallery-1 .gallery-item {\n\t\t\t\tfloat: left;\n\t\t\t\tmargin-top: 10px;\n\t\t\t\ttext-align: center;\n\t\t\t\twidth: 50%;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t#gallery-1 img {\n\t\t\t\tborder: 2px solid #cfcfcf;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t#gallery-1 .gallery-caption {\n\t\t\t\tmargin-left: 0;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t/* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */\n\t\t</style>\n\t\t<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-113 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-medium'><dl class='gallery-item'>\n\t\t\t<dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>\n\t\t\t\t<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/10406631_879797812043319_349665597571741998_n.jpg'><img width=\"300\" height=\"274\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/10406631_879797812043319_349665597571741998_n-300x274.jpg\" class=\"attachment-medium colorbox-113 \" alt=\"10406631_879797812043319_349665597571741998_n\" /></a>\n\t\t\t</dt></dl>\n\t\t\t<br style='clear: both' />\n\t\t</div>\n\n<p><a href=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/webcam/\"> </a></p>\n<h1> Wind Charts</h1>\n<p><a href=\"http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244\"><img class=\"size-thumbnail wp-image-747 alignleft\" title=\"wind guru\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/wind-guru-67x68.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"67\" height=\"68\" /></a> <a href=\"http://www.xcweather.co.uk/\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-749\" title=\"xcweathersmall\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/xcweathersmall2-67x68.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"67\" height=\"68\" /></a>       <a href=\"http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-750\" title=\"buoy weather\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/buoy-weather-67x68.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"67\" height=\"68\" /></a> <a href=\"http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244\">Wind Guru</a>       <a href=\"http://www.xcweather.co.uk/\">XC Weather</a>       <a href=\"http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e\">Buoy Weather</a></p>\n<h1>Swell Charts</h1>\n<p><a href=\"http://magicseaweed.com/Bundoran-Surf-Report/50/\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-753\" title=\"msw logo\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/msw-logo-67x43.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"75\" height=\"43\" /></a>             <a href=\"http://magicseaweed.com/UK-Ireland-MSW-Surf-Charts/1/\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-754\" title=\"magicseaweedwamchart\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/magicseaweedwamchart1-67x68.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"67\" height=\"68\" /></a>       <a href=\"http://www.marine.ie/Home/site-area/data-services/marine-forecasts/wave-forecasts\"><img class=\"alignnone wp-image-755 size-thumbnail\" title=\"marine institute irish bouy data\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/marine-institute-irish-bouy-data-67x42.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"67\" height=\"42\" /></a>                 <a href=\"http://magicseaweed.com/Bundoran-Surf-Report/50/\">Magic Seaweed</a>      <a href=\"http://magicseaweed.com/UK-Ireland-MSW-Surf-Charts/1/\">MSM WAM</a>          <a href=\"http://www.marine.ie/Home/site-area/data-services/marine-forecasts/wave-forecasts\">Marine Institute</a></p>\n<h1>Pressure, Weather, Tides</h1>\n<p><a href=\"http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/13000\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-756\" title=\"bbc pressure\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/bbc-pressure-67x68.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"67\" height=\"68\" /></a>          <a href=\"http://www.met.ie/\"><img class=\"alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-759\" title=\"met eireann\" src=\"http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/met-eireann-67x68.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"67\" height=\"68\" /></a>            <a href=\"http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/13000\">BBC Pressure</a>      <a href=\"http://www.met.ie/\">Met Eireann</a>      <a href=\"http://www.irishtimes.com/weather/tides.html\">Irish Tide Tables</a></p>\n
```

So in this JSON data, I've everything that I need, but how to select the good information ? Can we make a query ?
I would like to obtain this data (from screenshot)

[image: Screenshot]

How can I make that ?
I've another array called "excerpt" in JSON data with this data (just text that I need, without picture) : `<p>3rd March Swell is 5 foot and cross shore, bitter in the cold wind. Maybe streedagh. High tide: 1703 3.6m     CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM Low Tide: 1041 0.8m 3 day forecast to March 5th Good swell all weekend but the winds are changing. Keep in an eye for gaps in the wind. […]</p>\n` but can I drop HTML tag like `<p>` and skip a line after date for example (I thought about after "january, february, march..."[array], skip a line ?

Before High Tide, skip a line.
Before Low Tide, skip a line.
...

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but your JSON data looks very much like HTML. Please take a look at [this site](http://json.org/) to see what JSON is.

Comment: You will probably get no response because your question is just too broad. There are literally a million ways to accomplish what you are asking. I suggest you get yourself a nice ObjectiveC book/tutorial and learn how programming, parsing and working with HTML is done under iOS. Try by yourself, and come back later with a more specific question. I'd like to help you out more, but I just do not see how. Good luck!

Comment: Can you give me just one link for learning by myself ?

Comment: You probably want to programm for iOS with [ObjectiveC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/)

Comment: PS: The HTML data you receive can directly be integrated into web pages, you do not need to program anything if your iOS app is a web-app. You may just want to change the data slightly with Javascript.

Comment: @simpleBob I succeed to display a label with : "<p>3rd March Swell is 5 foot and cross shore, bitter in the cold wind. Maybe streedagh. High tide: 1703 3.6m     CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM Low Tide: 1041 0.8m 3 day forecast to March 5th Good swell all weekend but the winds are changing. Keep in an eye for gaps in the wind. [&hellip;]</p>"
But can I edit this ?

Comment: of course. For example with JS. Take a look at [strings](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)